# Perl `join` produces multi-line string

Tags: perl

I have this program to sort two arrays

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$movies = 'movies.txt';
open (FHD, $movies) || die " could not open $movies\n";
@movies = <FHD>;

$fruits = 'fruits.txt';
open (FHD, $fruits) || die " could not open $fruits\n";
@fruits = <FHD>;

@array3 = (@movies , @fruits);
@array3 = sort @array3;

print @array3;
```

When I run it I get something like this

```
apple
gi joe
iron man
orange
pear
star trek
the blind side
```

How can I change it to look like this?

```
apple, gi joe, iron man, orange, pear, star trek, the blind side
```

I know it has something got to do with `join`, but if I change my program to this it still prints the output on multiple lines

```
$value = join(', ', @array3); 
print "$value\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

The data in the arrays still has the newline at the end of each line read from the file. Use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to fix this.

You should also `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program.

It is best practice to use *lexical file handles* with the *three-parameter* form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and your `die` string should include the built-in `$!` variable to say *why* the `open` failed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $movies = 'movies.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $movies or die "Could not open '$movies': $!\n";
my @movies = <$fh>;
chomp @movies;


my $fruits = 'fruits.txt';
open $fh, '<', $fruits or die "Could not open '$fruits': $!\n";
my @fruits = <$fh>;
chomp @fruits;

my @array3 = sort @movies, @fruits;

print join(', ', @array3), "\n";
```

**output**

```
apple, gi joe, iron man, orange, pear, star trek, the blind side
```

Comment: I only receive water melon when i run the new program, the rest of the data didnt appeared!

Comment: @user3448790: Where did your file come from? I suspect you are running your program on a Linux system using data from a Windows system?

Comment: @user3448790: To get around this problem, replace `chomp @movies` with `s/\s+\z// for @movies`, and do the same for `@fruits`

Comment: Im using windows cygwin to run, and may i ask what does your suggestions mean?

Comment: Windows uses `CRLF` to terminate each line in a text file, whereas Linux uses just `LF`. So on a Linux-like system, `chomp` will remove just the `LF`, leaving `CR` which makes multiple lines overwrite each other. The substitution `s/\s+\z//` removes all "whitespace" at the end of a string, which includes `CR` and `LF` as well as `HT`, `FF` and space, so it will remove the line endings correctly regardless of what is there.