# Convert Arrays to Strings Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I have a movies.txt file that contains the following

```
    the blind side
    iron man
    star trek
    gi joe
```

I have tried to open this text file in perl using this

```
    open(FILEHANDLE,'movies.txt');
    @array2 =<FILEHANDLE>;
```

What command should I run so that I can have this following output?

```
   the blind side    iron man    star trey    gi joe
```

Comment: `join` won't get rid of the newlines though, will it?

Comment: What is wrong with [the answer I gave you here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723276/622310)? You seem to want the same output but without commas

Answer (score 4):

Removing newlines from every lines, join them with tab, then print the result. So the following code

```
chomp(@array2);
print (join "\t", @array2);
```

should be enough.

Comment: Nope, chomp(@array2) caused sgi joe to disappear and iron man and start trek to be stuck together

Comment: If `chomp(@array)` didn't work, then there's something about your data or your code that you aren't telling us.

Comment: @user3448790: We have already talked about Windows line endings. How come you seem to have forgotten about it altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Both [Lee Duhem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004301/lee-duhem) and [Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross) are on target about removing the newlines.  However, consider the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'movies.txt' or die "Can't open the movies file: $!";
chomp( my @movies = <$fh> );
print join ' ' x 4, @movies;
```

Output on your dataset:

```
the blind side    iron man    star trek    gi joe
```

Always *use strict; use warnings;* at the top of your scripts.  Use the [three-argument form of open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html).  Note that the movie titles are `join`ed using four spaces instead of a tab character.

Hope this helps!